# gwt javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call creating mapdb db

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, rpc, mapdb

Hi i take the MyWEbApp of GWT and tryed ok it worked, i needed to make a mapdb database, I imported mapDB and only added in server:

```
File utilizzo = new File("tipregotipregotiprego");
DB db;
db = DBMaker.newFileDB(utilizzo).closeOnJvmShutdown().make();
```

but it give me that error:

GRAVE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.mycompany.mywebapp.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mapdb/DBMaker
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that a jar is missing

```
Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.mycompany.mywebapp.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mapdb/DBMaker
```

Comment: but I added the library, in the folder war/web-inf-lib I can't understand why it's not working

Comment: If you try to run a small Java program (no GWT) in a main function with just these 2 lines does it work?

Comment: Maybe it was a typo but it's not web-inf-lib but WEB-INF\lib.

Comment: Do you get the error from eclipse? or you have deployed the project in Tomcat? Does the project compile? Have you added the jar in Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Libraries? I assume you are using eclipse

Comment: Yes, I'm using eclipse, no project error in compiling i added the library in war/web-inf/lib and added to the build path